# Is there a way to share a webradio on a network?

Tags: networking, streaming, internet-radio, shoutcast

At my work we try to limit the incoming bandwith from streaming webradio's. Therefore we want to stream a couple and then distribute/share them over our internal network.

Any suggestions on how to make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own webradion on your local network and streaming webradio from internet.

This is possible.

Look to [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/download)

Comment: +1 I second Shoutcast. You can play any audio input, and send it to the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast even videos on your network using [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html). I never tried, so I suggest you to read the documentation.